# What is the difference between graph.windows & graph.Microsoft

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

What is the difference in using graph.microsoft & graph.windows. ? I am using graph.microsoft authentication to grab user information from AD for a Chatbot.

previously I was using graph.windows and since there was not enough information available with result string I used graph.microsoft. I wonder in future it brings an issue if I use it for production?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will want to use Microsoft Graph (graph.microsoft) over Azure AD Graph (graph.windows). Both are still supported however Microsoft itself strongly recommends developers utilize the Microsoft Graph service.

You can read the original post from the Azure Graph team [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/) explaining the differences between the two. It's from 2016 so things have changed since then.

This [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-operations-overview), from November 2018, on Azure AD Graph, also recommends using Microsoft Graph.

Hope of help!